# AngularJS - ng-if - show when body has a class

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I want to show/hide an element using `ng-if`

e.g. I would like to show an element if body has got specific class

I've tried the following, but no success - is this even valid expression?

`<div ng-if="document.querySelector('body').className.indexOf('bodyHasThisClass') >= 0"></div`

Any suggestions much appreciated. Here is a plunk example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kzXXg0sne8nyQZuufao7?p=preview

---

From AngularJS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

*Angular expressions **do not have access to global variables like window, document or location**. This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding a controller to your directive

```
app.directive('wrapperDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'wrapper-directive.html',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.a = (document.querySelector('body').className.indexOf('bodyHasThisClass')>= 0)? true : false;
      $scope.b = (document.querySelector('body').className.indexOf('noSuchClass')===-1)? true:false;

    }
};
});
```

And in template:

```
<div ng-if="a==true">
    visible if body has class bodyHasThisClass
</div>
<div ng-if="b==false">
    this should be hidden
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking about adding a controller? How do I share this controller then, between different directives/controllers?